# Web responsive pages on Rails

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have already tried using:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but my mapbox does not respond to it.
When I open on the phone the page does not autofit the height.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of which part of the code you have pasted you expect to alter the height of the Mapbox element on your page.

Can you try setting the map height directly in your CSS?

If you have

`<div id="map"></div>`

The you could set the height in your CSS with

```
#map {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Where `vh` represents viewport height. 50vh will resolve to 50% of the current viewport height. And so 100vh should fill the entire vertical height of the screen. More on those viewport units at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/).